# Why does the graph disappear when I dynamically add edges with the vis-network.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vis.js, vis.js-network

It's strange that I'm using vis-network.js in my vue project, and the graphics disappear when I dynamically add edges.

But dynamic updates and deletes don't.

Then I wrote a test page introduced vis-network.js from https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js , and then found that is no problem!

So is there a problem with the vis-network downloaded from NPM?

Can someone help me?

How I use:

```
npm install vis-network


import vis from 'vis-network/dist/vis-network'
Vue.prototype.$vis = vis;


var nodes = new this.$vis.DataSet([
  {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
  {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
  {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
  {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
  {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
]);
var edges = new this.$vis.DataSet([
  {from: 1, to: 3},
  {from: 1, to: 2},
  {from: 2, to: 4},
  {from: 2, to: 5},
  {from: 3, to: 3}
]);
var data = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges
};
var container = document.getElementById("id");
var options = {};

this.graph = new this.$vis.Network(container, data, options);
nodes.add([{id:8, label:"Node 8"}]);  // normal
edges.add([{from:1 ,to:5}]);  // Graphics disappear
```

Answer (score 1):

I've spend all day banging my head against this exact problem as well, but in the end, I finally stumpled upon https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/2567

That issue has a very thorough explanation, but TL;DR: vis is build in a ways that simply doesn't work if you put your network into a vue components data.

It works to put the edges and nodes DataSets into component data, though, so keep references to those, and init the network without attaching it to the vue component.

Comment: You are a god. The things I would do for you.